# How do database indices make search faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I was reading through rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sidebar-database_indices) but confused about the explanation of database indicies, basically the author proposes that rather then searching O(n) time through the a list of emails (for login) its much faster to create an index, giving the following example:

> To understand a database index, it’s helpful to consider the analogy
>   of a book index. In a book, to find all the occurrences of a given
>   string, say “foobar”, you would have to scan each page for “foobar”.
>   With a book index, on the other hand, you can just look up “foobar” in
>   the index to see all the pages containing “foobar”.
>   **source**:
>   http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sidebar:database_indices**

So what I understand from that example is that words can be repeated in text, so the "index page" consists of unique entries. However, in the railstutorial site, the login is set such that each email address is unique to an account, so how does having an index make it faster when we can have at most one occurrence of each email?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indexing isn't (much) about duplicates. It's about order.

When you do a search, you want to have some kind of order that lets you (for example) do a binary search to find the data in logarithmic time instead of searching through every record to find the one(s) you care about (that's not the only type of index, but it's probably the most common).

Unfortunately, you can only arrange the records themselves in a single order.

An index contains just the data (or a subset of it) that you're going to use to search on, and pointers (or some sort) to the records containing the actual data. This allows you to (for example) do searches based on as many different fields as you care about, and still be able to do binary searching on all of them, because each index is arranged in order by that field.

Comment: is rails enforcing search alg. or the dbms?

Answer (score 4):

Because the index in the DB and in the given example is *sorted* alphabetically. The raw table / book is not. Then think: How do *you* search an index knowing it is sorted? I guess you don't start reading at "A" up to the point of your interest. Instead you skip roughly to the POI and start searching from there. Basically a DB can to the same with an index.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster because the index contains only values from the column in question, so it is spread across a smaller number of pages than the full table. Also, indexes usually include additional optimizations such as hash tables to limit the number of reads required.